# "then" executing before await has finished

Tags: jquery, ajax, async-await, filereader

I'm working on a project, where I need a form. I want to send my data via AJAX to my backend. I have a file upload and I need to convert the file to a base64, so I can save it into my database. I convert the file in jQuery with the FileReader. The problem is, that even if I added Promise() and await/async my AJAX function gets executed before the file was converted. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I don't get what it is.

Can anyone help, I don't get that working.
Thanks!

This is what I get in the console. You can see, that the file gets logged after the AJAX function and the file element is not in the log of the data that gets sent to the backend.
[image: Console]

My ajax.js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(async function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var children = $(this).find("input, textarea");
        console.log($(children).length);

        var nodeId = $(this).attr("data-nodeId");

        await loopChildren(children).then((allData) => ajaxCall(allData, nodeId))
    })
});

function loopChildren(children) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var allData = [];

        $(children).each(async function (index, elem) {
            var dataType = getDataType($(elem).attr("type"));

            await getContent(elem).then(function (content) {
                console.log("content " + index + " :" + content);
                allData.push({ "nodeId": parseInt($(elem).attr("id")), "content": content, "dataType": dataType });
            });
        })

        resolve(allData);
    })
}

function getContent(elem) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        if ($(elem).attr("type") == "checkbox" || $(elem).attr("type") == "radio") {
            resolve($(elem).is(":checked"));
        }
        else if ($(elem).attr("type") == "file") {
            for (var file of $(elem)[0].files) {
                await processFile(file).then(function (e) {
                    resolve(e)
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            resolve($(elem).val());
        }
    })
}

function readFileAsync(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = () => {
            resolve(reader.result);
        };

        reader.onerror = reject;

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    })
}

function processFile(file) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            await readFileAsync(file).then(function(content) {
                console.log(content);
                resolve(content);
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
        }
    })
}

function ajaxCall(myVeryOwnDataObject, nodeID) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myVeryOwnDataObject));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Umbraco/Api/Form/SendForm",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        headers: { 'nodeId': nodeID },
        data: JSON.stringify(myVeryOwnDataObject),
        success: function (success) {
            console.log(success);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
}

function getDataType(element) {
    switch (element) {
        case "text":
            return "text"
            break;
        case "textarea":
            return "textarea"
            break;
        case "number":
            return "number"
            break;
        case "email":
            return "text"
            break;
        case "tel":
            return "text"
            break;
        case "url":
            return "text"
            break;
        case "color":
            return "text"
            break;
        case "range":
            return "number"
            break;
        case "date":
            return "date"
            break;
        case "datetime-local":
            return "dateTime"
            break;
        case "month":
            return "date"
            break;
        case "time":
            return "time"
            break;
        case "file":
            return "file"
            break;
        case "checkbox":
            return "check"
            break;
        case "radio":
            return "check"
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your `loopChildren` function.

Although you have an `await` before the `getContent` call, that promise is essentially being dropped because there is nothing `await`ing on the async function that creates it.

The way this function executes is:

- create a new Promise
- declare a variable called `allData`
- loop through each element in `children` and create an async function for each
- resolve the Promise with the value of `allData`, which is an empty array because we did not `await` on the result of our `.each` loop

To fix this, I would use `.map` instead of `.each` so as to map each element of `children` into a Promise. I would then use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to await the resolution of *all* of these Promises. We can directly return the `Promise.all` from `loopChildren` and do away with the `new Promise`.

The function becomes:

```
function loopChildren(children) {
  const getContentPromises = $(children).map(function (index, elem) {
    var dataType = getDataType($(elem).attr("type"));

    return getContent(elem).then(content => {
      return {
        "nodeId": parseInt($(elem).attr("id")),
        "content": content,
        "dataType": dataType
      };
    });
  });

  return Promise.all(getContentPromises);
}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/bgto2rze/) that mocks-out the flow of Promise resolution.